# Remove extra spaces in between from grid of pie charts

Tags: android, android-layout, mpandroidchart

I have made pie charts  using mp-android chart.I have placed 9 charts in a grid but there is extra spaces between them.I need to remove those  necessary spaces and make the edges touch each other.

This is the java method which inflates each piechart,I have tried the previous answers  but nothing works.

```
 static void makePie(PieChart pieChart, int type, boolean spin, Context con){

    pieChart.setExtraOffsets(-30, -30, -30, -30);

    ArrayList<PieEntry> yvalues = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i=0;i<type;i++){
        yvalues.add(new PieEntry(10F, ""));
    }
    PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(yvalues, "Net Worth");
    ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();

    PieData data = new PieData(dataSet);
    pieChart.setCenterTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    pieChart.setData(data);

    pieChart.setDrawHoleEnabled(false);
    final int[] MY_COLORS = {
            Color.rgb(246,230,196),
            Color.rgb(200,237,253),
            Color.rgb(252,199,202),
            Color.rgb(179,233,216),
            Color.rgb(247,233,174),
            Color.rgb(211,211,246),
            Color.rgb(108,59,57),
            Color.rgb(75,132,138),
            Color.rgb(124,96,66),
            Color.rgb(247,173,89),
            Color.rgb(235,108,63),
            Color.rgb(208,75,52),
            Color.rgb(255,202,39),
            Color.rgb(147,37,166),
            Color.rgb(22,158,250),
            Color.rgb(118,7,47),
            Color.rgb(44,183,80),
            Color.rgb(100,22,151),
            Color.rgb(88,42,71),
            Color.rgb(27,40,121),
            Color.rgb(29,112,74),
            Color.rgb(252,216,82),
            Color.rgb(247,99,64),
            Color.rgb(232,57,52)
    };

    ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    dataSet.setColors(colors);
    for(int i=0;i<type;i++){
        colors.add(getRandom(MY_COLORS));
    }





    List<LegendEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    dataSet.setDrawValues(false);
    data.setValueTextSize(16f);
    data.setValueTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    pieChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    pieChart.setTransparentCircleAlpha(0);
    pieChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
    pieChart.setRotationEnabled(false);
    pieChart.setClickable(false);
    pieChart.setTouchEnabled(false);


    pieChart.setExtraOffsets(-10,0,-10,0);
    pieChart.invalidate();
    if(spin){
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(con, R.anim.rotate);
        pieChart.startAnimation(animation);

    }

}
```

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mIPMjFW3BlWhWLfQWIV65sfx9FO091pv

This is the output, there are spaces between the grids, which is taking too much space, andneeded to be removed so that the piecharts touch each other,

Comment: what is this PieChart class?
are you using a library?
if yes would you name the library that you are using?

Comment: Im using MPAndroid Pie Chart

Answer (score 0):

I've tried my self then I changed the setExtraOffsets in your code
it had an effect on the padding of your view but the shape was not circled any more
I recommend to remove setExtraOffsets in your code and see the result.
mention that you are using setExtraOffsets two parts of your code